# .NET Core Angular TypeScript

Tags: c#, angularjs, node.js, typescript, asp.net-core

I have made web application using asp .net core and typescript. In local machine when I run from VS it works, but when I published to IIS I get an error. Since I'm quite new in typescript and .net core, for the beginning I'm giving you only the an error. Please tell me which code else should I show in order to help to solve my problem.

error log:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
>         ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null
>             at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83658:31)
>             at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83629:17)
>             at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83706:17
>             at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83315:31)
>             at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14877:37)
>             at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83314:36)
>             at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83082:47)
>             at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83475:35)
>             at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83381:25)
>             at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:84293:25)
>           rejection: 
>            Response {
>              _body: 
>               ProgressEvent {
>                 type: 'error',
>                 target: [Object],
>                 currentTarget: [Object],
>                 lengthComputable: false,
>                 loaded: 0,
>                 total: 0 },
>              status: 0,
>              ok: false,
>              statusText: '',
>              headers: Headers { _headers: Map {}, _normalizedNames: Map {} },
>              type: 3,
>              url: null },
>           promise: 
>            ZoneAwarePromise {
>              __zone_symbol__state: 0,
>              __zone_symbol__value: 
>               Response {
>                 _body: [Object],
>                 status: 0,
>                 ok: false,
>                 statusText: '',
>                 headers: [Object],
>                 type: 3,
>                 url: null } },
>           zone: 
>            Zone {
>              _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
>              _parent: 
>               Zone {
>                 _properties: {},
>                 _parent: null,
>                 _name: '',
>                 _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
>              _name: 'angular',
>              _zoneDelegate: 
>               ZoneDelegate {
>                 _taskCounts: [Object],
>                 zone: [Circular],
>                 _parentDelegate: [Object],
>                 _forkZS: null,
>                 _forkDlgt: null,
>                 _forkCurrZone: [Object],
>                 _interceptZS: null,
>                 _interceptDlgt: null,
>                 _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
>                 _invokeZS: [Object],
>                 _invokeDlgt: [Object],
>                 _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
>                 _handleErrorZS: [Object],
>                 _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
>                 _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
>                 _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
>                 _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
>                 _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
>                 _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
>                 _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
>                 _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
>                 _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
>                 _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
>                 _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
>                 _hasTaskZS: [Object],
>                 _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
>                 _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
>                 _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
>           task: 
>            ZoneTask {
>              _zone: 
>               Zone {
>                 _properties: [Object],
>                 _parent: [Object],
>                 _name: 'angular',
>                 _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
>              runCount: 0,
>              _zoneDelegates: null,
>              _state: 'notScheduled',
>              type: 'microTask',
>              source: 'Promise.then',
>              data: undefined,
>              scheduleFn: undefined,
>              cancelFn: null,
>              callback: [Function],
>              invoke: [Function] } } info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
>         Executed action RnDFiorano.Controllers.HomeController.Index (RnDFiorano) in 1526.7257ms fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for
>   URL: null
>       at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83658:31)
>       at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83629:17)
>       at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83706:17
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83315:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14877:37)
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83314:36)
>       at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83082:47)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83475:35)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83381:25)
>       at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:84293:25)
>   System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error:
>   Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null
>       at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83658:31)
>       at resolvePromise (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83629:17)
>       at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83706:17
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83315:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14877:37)
>       at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83314:36)
>       at Zone.module.exports.Zone.runTask (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83082:47)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83475:35)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:83381:25)
>       at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rnd\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:84293:25)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.d__7`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.<InvokeExportAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper.d__33.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml.d__31.MoveNext() in
>   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml:line 2
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.d__26.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__30.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__28.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

All TS are managed on this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

import { SparePart } from '../../shared/spare-part.type';
import { SparePartService } from '../../shared/spare-part.service';

import {MachineType} from '../../shared/machine-type.type';
import { MachineTypeService } from '../../shared/machine-type.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'spare-part-list',
    templateUrl: './spare-part-list.component.html',
    providers: [SparePartService, MachineTypeService],


})

export class SparePartListComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() sparePart: SparePart;

    spareParts: SparePart[];

    maschines: MachineType[];

    constructor(private sparePartService: SparePartService, private machineTypeService: MachineTypeService,private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sparePartService.getSpareParts()
            .then(items => this.spareParts = items);
        this.machineTypeService.getMachineTypes()
            .then(items => this.maschines = items);
    }

    navigateToNew() {
        this.router.navigate(["newItem"]);
    }

}


import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { SparePart } from './spare-part.type';

@Injectable()
export class SparePartService {



    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
    }

    getSpareParts() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items')
            .map(response => response.json() as SparePart[])
            .toPromise();
    }

    postSparePart(sparePart: SparePart) {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items', sparePart)
            .toPromise();
    }
}
```

Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Typescript has nothing to do with IIS, it gets compiled to JS and runs in the browser, iis only serves the js files

Comment: I know that, but I must mention what I did and when stop to work.

Comment: Did you use JavaScriptServices for creating Angular with TypeScript?

Comment: No, currently not using.